# facebook connect and twitter connect in Zend Framework

Tags: facebook, zend-framework, twitter

Is there any library class exists written in Zend, for following two:
1. Facebook 
2. Twitter

It doesn't have to be single class, two different classes for two services will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dealing with Twitter REST API you can use [Zend_Service_Twitter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html), as for facebook you could try this [zend facebook library](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/scriptDownload/Zend-Framework-Facebook-Library-Download-66528.html) ( i haven't used it and it doesn't look like it will provide too many facebook features )